# How to copy (and rename) a database?

Tags: delphi, odbc, ado

I am coding in Delphi, using a TADOConnection to access ODBC compliant databases.

How do I copy a database leaving the new copy on the same database server?

And how do I rename? (I suppose I could copy & delete the original - if I knew how to copy).

Comment: Would be interested to know what problem/requirement you're trying to address with the "copy database" solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ODBC does not provide for the copying or creating databases. That is a technology-specific (specific to the RDBMS) facility. The closest you can get is by creating and populating (copying) tables.

The only way you could do it would be to issue a db-specific command via an ODBC connection but for that we would have to know exactly what type of database you're using.

Comment: +1 That's what I feared. Currently only MySQl, but I expect others later (Access, Oracle ...)

Comment: You're casting a pretty wide net. Unfortunately i think that even db-specific commands will work. For example, I don't think Access provides any such facility at all. Your best bet will be to create an algorithm per db-type you want to support and use a DI process to do your db copying: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection

Comment: @Leonix: I can see you have no previous experience with oracle... what you say (copy a database) is meaningless for a Oracle database, maybe you mean to create a different instance and populate it with the same data, or maybe to create a different schema on the same instance... but a database copy, I don't think so...

Answer (score 1):

Are you using ODBC drivers, or ADO providers?  If the later, you can look into the ADOX library, which provides vendor neutral support for working with the structure of databases.  I don't know myself whether it supports operations on the entire database.